# Interface not registered(0x80040155) when running Pex On Specific machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pex

### Pex 0.94.0.0 Release Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1 Bug Report

How to reproduce:

1. Open a class library project
2. Create an empty method
3. Right Click->Run Pex

I run without problem on another machine (In Office, VS2010 Utimate)

But I got this exception on my home computer(VS2010 Professtional)

---

exception details:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EnvDTE.DTE'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
'{04A72314-32E9-48E2-9B87-A63603454F3E}') failed due to the following error: Interface not registered. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155)
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.VsServiceProviderHelper.GetService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Helpers.ProjectHelper.SaveAllFiles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Actions.ActionComponent.SaveAll()
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Actions.ExplorationActionBase.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Actions.ActionComponent.Execute(Object target)

---

Current stacktrace
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Controls.ErrorReport.CreateReport(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Controls.ErrorReport.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Pex.VsPackage.Helpers.UIThreadInvoker.SafeMethodInvoker.Invoke()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

---

relevant environment variables:
COR_ENABLE_PROFILER=
COR_PROFILER=
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86

---

machine data:
processor count = 4

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be some weird registry problem
Reinstalling Windows can solve it